# Django page not found when deleting object with foreign key (1 to many)

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, delete-file

This is my first time trying to delete objects with a foreign key. The models have a 1 to many relationship:

```
class NumObject(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number= models.IntegerField()
    ident= models.IntegerField()
    usersave= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank= True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NumObject,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})

class Sounds(models.Model):
    numobj = models.ForeignKey(NumObject)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sound = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'title': self.title})
```

The views for the NumObject and Sounds look like this:

```
def post_detail(request,id= None):
    instance= get_object_or_404(NumObject, id=id)

    context= {
        'title': instance.number,
        'instance': instance,



}
    return render(request,'post_detail.html',context)

def sound_detail(request,id= None):
    instancesound= get_object_or_404(Sounds, id=id)


    context= {
        'sound': instance.number,
        'instancesound': instancesound,
}
    return render(request,'sound_detail.html',context)
```

in my template, I'm able to display all "Sounds" objects associated with a "NumObject" object by doing this:

```
{% for obj in instance.sounds_set.all %}
{% include 'sound_detail.html' %}    
{% endfor %}
```

sound_detail.html has a ul that displays all the sound objects, as well as a link to the delete view for each sound object:

```
<a href="/{{instance.id}}/delete/">Delete</a>
```

The url for the delete view looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/delete/$', views.post_delete, name= 'delete'),
```

And the delete view:

```
def post_delete(request, id):
    sound= get_object_or_404(Sounds, pk=id).delete()

    return redirect('posts:list')
```

For some reason, when I try and delete the  individual "Sounds" object, I get "Page not found" with the request URL of http://127.0.0.1:8000/8/delete/, and an error "No Sounds matches the given query."(which looks alright to me). Having the hardest time trying to understand whats going on, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 8 is the wrong id. It's the NumObject id not the Sounds id. You are not passing the sounds_set to the sounds_detail.html page.

Try the following:

1) Change your template to instead include sound_detail with a passed variable:

`{% include 'sound_detail.html' with sound=obj %}`

2) On the sound_detail page, change the link to:

`<a href="/{{sound.id}}/delete/">Delete</a>`

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try it out and get back to you

Comment: You're the BEST. Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.